# How to "select" an element of a glyph from a Dropdown menu in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to "select" an element in a figure via the dropdown menu using Bokeh . In the example below I define the figure and the properties of a selected element. The element can be selected by tapping on it and its color will change accordingly (to "firebrick"). What I don't know how to do is how to select the element via the dropdown menu so that the figure changes accordingly, that is if I chose the element with x=2 from the dropdown the figure will reflect that (the x=2 element in the figure will turn "firebrick" color). Without using JS.
Any help greatly appreciated.

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Circle
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

from bokeh.models.widgets import Dropdown, Select

#create figure with tap
TOOLS = 'tap'
plot = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=600, tools=TOOLS)

# Create Data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 4, 9, 16]
trace_source = ColumnDataSource({'x':x, 'y':y})

# Create trace
trace = plot.circle(x='x',y='y', source = trace_source, size=20, color='red')
trace.selection_glyph = Circle(fill_alpha=1, fill_color='firebrick',line_color='firebrick')

# Create dropdown
dropdown = Dropdown(label="Select x-value",
                    button_type="warning",
                    menu=[(str(x[i]),str(x[i])) for i in range(len(x)) ])

# define behavior of tap
def tap_callback(attr, old, new):
    print('You selected the first trace')
    print('attr: ',attr)
    print('old:', old)
    print('new:', new)
    return
trace.data_source.selected.on_change('indices', tap_callback)

# define behavior of dropdown
def drop_selected(attr, old, new):
    print(float(new))
    return
dropdown.on_change('value',drop_selected)


curdoc().add_root(row(plot,dropdown))
curdoc()
```

Answer (score 0):

CDS selections can be assigned to:

```
trace.data_source.selected.indices = [10]
```